# rest api count column data

Tags: api, rest, parse-platform

Is it possible with the Parse REST API to query for column data and have it return count in for each type encountered in that column?

For instance:

column1   column2    column3

type3     type1      type3

type3     type3      type1

type3     type1      type4

type3     type1      type3

So, I want the number of type 3's, 2's, and 1's in column3 returned like:

type3 = 2

type1 = 1

type4 = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can send a query via the REST-API and pass in the parameter count=1 to only return the number of possible results instead of the actual objects.

Here is an example I took from the documentation [1]:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: YOUR_APP_ID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: YOUR_REST_API_KEY" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"column3":"type3"}' \
  --data-urlencode 'count=1' \
  --data-urlencode 'limit=0' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/YOUR_CLASSNAME
```

[1] https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#queries-counting